# mdx.macro: Path must be a string. Received undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I basically want to do this:
    
    `` importMDX(`../${variable}.mdx`); ``

But the only thing that works is this:
    
    `importMDX('../filename.mdx');`

Is using variables in the `importMDX()` function not supported at all or am i missing something? I've looked throught the documentation for MDX but they give no examples of doing what i want to do, but they don't state that this is not supported either.

Documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdx.macro

I basically want to do what they do in their example but using a variable as/in the filepath

```
import { importMDX } from './mdx.macro'

const myVariable = './my-document.mdx'; //I want to do this
const MyDocument = React.lazy(() => importMDX(myVariable))//Here

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
    <MyDocument />
  </React.Suspense>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```